# pg_fetch_all and pg_fetch_assoc efficiency

Tags: php, postgresql

Is `pg_fetch_all` function more efficient than the snippet

```
while( $res = pg_fetch_assoc($rs) ) 
{
    $out[] = $res;
}
```

I am wondering how `pg_fetch_all` is internally implemented. I want to know whether the while- approach is (much) less efficient than using this function and why.

Comment: Try benchmarking them?

Comment: I want more theoretical answer. Like, what should be rather than what is.

Comment: @onerror, then maybe this isn't the proper forum

Comment: @onerror Why on earth would you want a "theoretical" answer over getting the actual answer...?

Comment: It is a site where programmers help each other in their work after all. Do you have ideas on how pg_fetch_all works internally? I want to know which approach is better and whether I can count on the while- approach without disadvantages in comparison with the pg_fetch_all approach.

Comment: You can find the implementation for pg_fetch_all [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pgsql/pgsql.c#L2913). Efficiency wise, I expect them to be similar, potentially to the point that you wouldn't notice the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Internally both snippets include cycles looping through all the fetched rows, so they are quite similar in terms of efficiency. [internal implementation of pg_fetch_all](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pgsql/pgsql.c#L2913)